# deep link to launch the installed app from browser(chrome) not worked for second time on android devices

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, intentfilter, deep-linking

```
In my case it opens the installed android app first time on chrome,
```

second time it shows blank page. if i clear the cache data of chrome app then again it opens the installed app,again second time same blank page.
this is my java script code
    Please help anyone.Thank you in advance

```
     mobileDeepLink.js
     var wUrl='';
     function LaunchApp(){
     wUrl="gpscheme://gpandroid/signup?id="XXx";
     window.open(wUrl);
     }
     function mobileDeepLink()
     { 
      LaunchApp();  
     }
the following is my html code  

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="android-app://com.example/gpscheme/gpandroid" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="mobileDeepLink()">
    <script src="http://192.168.0.113:3000/GPWeb/gpjs/mobileDeepLink.js">        </script>
    </body>
    </html>

and in my android manifest file  

    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <data
                android:host="gpandroid"
                android:scheme="gpscheme"
                />                
    </intent-filter>
```